# What's the difference between BindableObject and ObservableObject?

Tags: swift, swiftui

With `ObservableObject` you `@Publish` a value. With `BindableObject` you implement `didChange`.

When would you use one of the other? I'm watching a video tutorial and, out of nowhere, they're using `BindableObject`, which I've never seen before.

Comment: `BindableObject` is outdated - it is absent in released SwiftUI.

Comment: ah, they must have not updated that part of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BindableObject:

- Introduced in early versions of SwiftUI.
- Deprecated in later SwiftUI versions (macOS 10.15.4, iOS 13.4, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2).
- Conformed to this protocol when you wanted to manually send
  willChange.send() to announce changes.

For current SwiftUI projects, it’s recommended to use ObservableObject with @Published properties. If you encounter BindableObject in older code or tutorials, understand that it’s an outdated protocol, and you should use ObservableObject instead.